# PHP Composer include file with defined "use namespace as" statements, append to each file

Tags: php, namespaces, include, composer-php, autoloader

I know you can use Composer's `files` scheme to include functions or definitions automatically in [every file](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files).

I'd like to take this one step further and *never* have to manually write a `use classname as` statement again in individual files. This is my ideal set up:

`/composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "2.*"
    }
    "autoload": {
        "files": ["init.php"]
    }
}
```

`/init.php`:

```
use Slim\Slim as Slim;
use Slim\Route as Route;
define("RYAN","BRODIE");
```

`/example.php`:

```
require '/vendor/autoload.php';
echo RYAN; //  ✔ outputs "BRODIE"
new Slim(); //  × Fatal error: Class 'Slim' not found
```

This way whenever I add a new namespace or class to an existing namespace, I can add it to `init.php` and then use it as I so wish across all of the repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you modify the PHP runtime, this is not possible. `namespace` and `use` declarations are only valid in the physical file they appear in. These declarations do not span across `include`s. If they did you'd have a real nightmare managing namespaces and aliases.

Declaring these at the top of each file is simply something you'll have to live with. Most languages that have features similar to PHP's namespaces do the same.

[Link to documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php).

Comment: I agree with not being able to set `namespace`'s across files, obvious logic to that, but `use as statements`? The error could be just the same as if you set the same alias twice within 1 file. Will mark correct when you link to documentation (which I couldn't find before posting QS :D), not that I don't believe you.

Comment: It's really not uncommon to have classes of the same name in separate namespaces. In fact, that's exactly what namespaces were designed for. If you alias them and aliases span across files, you're back at square one with regards to avoiding naming conflicts, only this time called "alias conflicts".

Comment: I understand the point of namespaces or I clearly wouldn't of implemented them. I'm not saying the above wouldn't work for *everyone*, but it'd work for some.

Comment: And *I* am saying it would largely negate the point of namespaces, therefore it doesn't work. :) Here's your documentation BTW: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: Apologies for my jackassery